# Problem detecting yaml-cpp in Hydro installation on MACOS Maveriks

Tags: ros, yaml, ros-hydro, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ROS hydro on a macbook running Maveriks 10.9.5.  The machine setup was cloned from a Lion machine which means I've had some problems with out-of-date dependencies and so on.  My current problem comes when the system tries to build  camera_calibration_parsers which fails with the error

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (if):
if given arguments:

```
"VERSION_GREATER" "0.5"
```

Unknown arguments specified

I *have* managed to do a fresh-ish install of ROS on an iMAC running Maveriks 10.9.5 so I suspect the problem is legacy libraries on this machine.  By comparing the two installations it looks like the build is failing to instantiate YAML_CPP_VERSION (and a bunch of other YAML based variables used by cmake)

The problem may be that yaml doesn't appear in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages but instead appears in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages . I've uninstalled and reinstalled pip (making sure I have the correct version) but this doesn't seem to have made a difference.  rosdep claims to be able to find everything it needs.

I'm a little wary of trying something drastic (like deleting the contents of /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages) so was wondering if anyone had a clearer idea why catkin_make_isolated can't detect yaml properly

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201523/problem-detecting-yaml-cpp-in-hydro-installation-on-macos-maveriks/) by [Louise](https://answers.ros.org/users/3671/louise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2015-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-22**:
Isn't `yaml-cpp` a C++ library, not a Python library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes.  I finally tracked the problem down to the fact that pkg-config was not installed in /usr/local/bin for some reason.

---

Originally posted by [Louise](https://answers.ros.org/users/3671/louise/) with karma: 16 on 2015-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [filipposanfilippo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21802/filipposanfilippo/) on 2016-04-16**:
Can you please explain how did you fix the problem in detail?